# Introduction to algorithms A creative approach Exercise 5.25

Tags: algorithm, graph, colors, tree

Below is the exercise 5.25 in 《Introduction to algorithms, a creative approach》. After reading it several times, I still can't understand what it means. I can color a tree with 2 colors very easily and directly using the method it described, not 1+LogN colors.

《Begin》
This exercise is related to the wrong algorithm for determining whether a graph is bipartite, described in Section 5.11.In some sense, this exercise shows that not only is the algorithm wrong, but also the simple approach can not work. Consider the more general problem of graph coloring: Given an undirected graph G=(V,E), a valid coloring of G is an assignment of colors to the vertices such that no two adjacent vertices have the same color. The problem is to find a valid coloring, using as few colors as possible. (In general, this is a very difficult problem; it is discussed in Chapter 11.)

Thus, a graph is bipartite if it can be colored with two colors.

A. Prove by induction that trees are always bipartite.

B. We assume that the graph is a tree(which means that the graph is bipartite). We want to find a partition of the vertices into the two subsets such that there are no edges connecting vertices within one subset. 
    Consider again the wrong algorithm for determining whether a graph is bipartite, given in Section 5.11: We take an arbitrary vertex, remove it, color the rest(by induction), and then color the vertex in the best possible way. That is, we color the vertex with the oldest possible color, and add a new color only if the vertex is connected to vertices of all the old colors. Prove that, if we color one vertex at a time regardless of the global connections, we may need up to 1+logN colors. 
    You should design a construction that maximizes the number of colors for every order of choosing vertices. The construction can depend on the order in the following way.
    The algorithm picks a vertex as a next vertex and starts checking the vertex’s edges. At that point, you are allowed to add edges incident to this vertex as you desire, provided that the graph remains a tree, such that, at the end, the maximal number of colors will be required. You can not remove an edge after it is put in(that would be cleanining the algorithm, which has already seen the edge). The best way to achieve this construction is by induction. Assume that you know a construction that requires<=k colors with few vertices, and build one that requires k+1 colors without adding too many new vertices.
《End》

Comment: What do you not understand? The algorithm to color the graph with `1 + log n` colors is described right there

Comment: The exercise is requiring you to design the algorithm. Does it show the algorithm?